# Video doesnot show correctly

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using rox videoView to show video on Xamarin.

My XAML content is

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
  <rox:VideoView AutoPlay="True"
                  LoopPlay="True"
                  ShowController="True"
                  Source="http://fightathlete.com.rose.arvixe.com//Upload/Late%20For%20Work.mp4" />
</Grid>
```

This loads the video and run perfectly, but doesnot show anything. i listen the audio perfectly. what is the problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your `Grid` some `Width` and `Height`.

For example:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <rox:VideoView AutoPlay="True"
                  LoopPlay="True"
                  ShowController="True" Source="http://fightathlete.com.rose.arvixe.com//Upload/Late%20For%20Work.mp4" />
</Grid>
```